# In React Native, how can I convert (colour) text to an image I can manipulate?

Tags: text, react-native, image-manipulation, emoji, glyph

I'm new to React Native and don't know if this is even possible.

I want to render a string of text into something like a bitmap, canvas, etc where I can manipulate it as an image.

It needs to work with colour text such as emojis.

Is this too low level for stock React Native?

Comment: Have you considered using an SVG for your purposes?

Comment: for example: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg